# tramp mode will not work (ssh cannot resolve hostname)?

Tags: emacs, ssh, tramp

Earlier this week I tried ssh'ing into my lab machine (as I do very frequently) via tramp mode (ubuntu 14.04) and now it seems to not work out of the blue. I have tried checking all folder permissions, that ssh actually works (in terminal, even nested in emacs). However, it still will not connect me. I see the connection in my .ssh file so I am not sure what the issue is. Any ideas? This is killing my productivity since I would much rather tramp in vs git everything.

```
######### from C-x C-f ssh:user@host...etc (which has always worked in the past) #######
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: Name or service not known

########## from *Messages buffer* #####################
Tramp: Opening connection for ssh using scp...
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh   -e none ssh'

Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh   -e none ssh'
Tramp: Opening connection for ssh using scp...done
byte-code: Process died
```

**side note:** I did start having pop-ups w/ system program problem detected but the ONLY thing in the /var/crash folder is a virtual box issue so I cant imagine that could be it. (Can I purge emacs and grab my config again and solve it that way?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message clearly indicates that you are doing `C-x C-f /ssh:user@host/path/to/file`. A colon is missing after `host`. Pls open this like `C-x C-f /ssh:user@host:/path/to/file`.

Comment: wow. I Feel pretty dumb, I usually auto-complete with ido so guess I had been getting lazy